# How can I make the content of a grid element not affect its size?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Basically i just want the four boxes in the snippet below to be the same size while still having the text centered inside the first box. Right now the text 'qwe' affects the size of the first box. Also it has to be using display: grid, like it is now.

```css
.asd {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4 1fr);
}

.asd > div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.box1 {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 1/2;
}

.box4 {
    grid-column: 2/3;
  grid-row: 2/3;
}
```

```html
<div class="asd">
  <div class="box1">qwe</div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
  <div class="box3"></div>
  <div class="box4"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your css is **invalid** `grid-template-columns: repeat(4 1fr);grid-template-rows: repeat(4 1fr);`

**use**

`grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;`

If the text grow out of the box use `overflow: hidden;`

```css
.asd {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
}

.asd > div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="asd">
  <div class="box1">qwe qwe qwe</div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
  <div class="box3"></div>
  <div class="box4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: tell me for more help

Comment: The box still grows if i add more text. I want it to always have the same size. And if the text doesn't fit it should just go outside of the box.

Comment: do you want scroll if the text too long?

Comment: No, i just want the text to grow outside of the box, or if that's not possible just have it hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Add height and width to 50px of each div as the asd is 100px

```css
.asd {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4 1fr);
}

.asd > div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;

}

.box1 {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 1/2;
}

.box4 {
    grid-column: 2/3;
  grid-row: 2/3;
}
```

```html
<div class="asd">
  <div class="box1">aqs</div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
  <div class="box3"></div>
  <div class="box4"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use minmax() so it won't use the minimum content size as minimum width for that column.

```
.mygrid
{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(0, 1fr) minmax(0, 1fr) minmax(0, 1fr) minmax(0, 1fr);
}
```

Also you may want to tell the browser to break the text lines in the middle of a word (if it fails to find a good spot to wrap). This is especially useful in case you have long links in your text:

```
.mygrid__item
{
  word-break: break-word;
}
```